# Why do we select random hash function in Universal Hashing

Tags: algorithm, hash

As per the definition of Universal Hashing , a random hash function is selected to to have a good worst case garuntee. But I am unable to understand how it works.

Suppose if I select some random Hash Function h , still there is a chance to ending up with the worst set of elements possbile.

Pleas explain in simple words.

I have seen the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7QSM_hlS1U . But it is difficult to understand

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but unlikely. The guarantees you have are probabilistic (i.e. expected value or "with high probability" bounds)

Comment: @NiklasB. Any intuition why it unlikely. If the function itself is selected randomly , how does it effect.

Comment: Probability of the having worst Set decreases as the number of different hash functions available to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: using a random hash function does not 100% prevent you from ending up with a worst case set. But in the lecture you provided, the main concern is that an enemy might be able to predict an input that always yields to a worst case scenario.

As an example he used a competitor that has to choose a benchmark for your hash table. Without using a random hash function at runtime, he would know the hash function you use and could predict which keys would yield to the same hash value and thus transform the hash table to a linked list (since each key is assigned to the same bucket). A deterministic hash function carries this risk of a predictable worst-case outcome, which is especially bad in an adversary setting.

By using a random hash function at runtime, even if the enemy chooses the benchmark, you are guaranteed with a certain probability that there are no collisions. 
More specific, when you have the values x and y (with x != y) and you choose a function h from m different hash functions H, then (quite intuitively) the probability that h(x) = h(y) is AT LEAST smaller than 1/m, i.e., 1/m sets an upper probability bound. A deterministic hash function cannot give you this property.

Also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing)